# Clojurescript: No such namespace: ring.middleware.anti-forgery

Tags: clojurescript, ring, reagent

Can't import ring.middleware.anti-forgery

```
(ns msa-debugger-clojure.core
(:require
[reagent.core :as r :refer [atom]]
[reagent.session :as session]
[reitit.frontend :as reitit]
[clerk.core :as clerk]
[accountant.core :as accountant]
[reagent-forms.core :refer [bind-fields]]
[reagent-forms.core :as reagent-forms]
[ring.middleware.anti-forgery :as anti-forgery]
```

))

As said in readme, add dependency to project.clj:

```
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
             [ring-server "0.5.0"]
             [reagent "0.8.1"]
             [reagent-utils "0.3.2"]
             [ring "1.7.1"]
             [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]
             [ring/ring-anti-forgery "1.3.0"]
             [hiccup "1.0.5"]
             [yogthos/config "1.1.1"]
             [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.520"
              :scope "provided"]
             [metosin/reitit "0.2.13"]
             [pez/clerk "1.0.0"]
             [venantius/accountant "0.2.4"
              :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.reader]]
             [reagent-forms "0.5.43"]
            ]
```

What i am doing wrong? :c

Comment: Hello, Alexey. Can you specify readme and repository please?

Comment: @cyberra https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-anti-forgery

Comment: Also, can you specify the error message please?

Comment: Done this in luminus guestbook tutorial, worked fine. Imported as well.

Answer (score 0):

`ring` is a Clojure library and does not work in ClojureScript.